# Use of compose function

Tags: scala

This code :

```
  def compose[A, B, C](f: B => C, g: A => B): A => C =
    a => f(g(a))                                  //> compose: [A, B, C](f: B => C, g: A => B)A => C

    def f(a : Int) = a + 1                    //> f: (a: Int)Int
    def g(a : Int) = a + 1                    //> g: (a: Int)Int


    compose[Int,Int,Int](f(1) , g(1))
```

causes compiler error :

```
Multiple markers at this line - type mismatch; found : Int required: Int => Int - type mismatch; found : Int 
 required: Int => Int
```

But since f and g are functions which take an Int and return an Int, does this not match function definition of `f: B => C` as B & C will be typed to an Int ?

Comment: You must pass a function to `compose`, not the result of a function invocation. `f(1)` is `2`, which does not have the type `B => C`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should compose functions (you're composing Ints).
As a result you get another function which is the composition.
Then you can pass the parameter to the composed function.

```
compose[Int,Int,Int](f , g)(1)
```

BTW, there's a `compose` (and `andThen`) method in Scala

```
(f _).compose(g)(1)
```

https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/pattern-matching-and-functional-composition.html